# Is node-mysql available when using sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, node-mysql

I believe that Sequelize utilizes node-mysql in the background? Not sure about this. If it is, I'm wondering if there is any way to use it. Sequelize starts to fall down when you want to do complex multi table queries. But there is no way to run hand rolled sql queries with it using parameterized queries, or escaping input. Node-Mysql does all that. So, it would be nice to be able to use Sequelize when it makes sense, and node-mysql when it makes sense, without having to set up a new connection.

Answer (score 0):

After scanning the documentation for a few seconds, I found this:

[Executing raw SQL queries](http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#usage-raw-queries)

```
sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM myTable").success(function(myTableRows) {
  console.log(myTableRows)
})
```

Comment: No, that doesn't answer the question. The question is about parameterized queries. I know I can run a raw sql query. But if i want to pass data into it that has come from the web, it needs to be dealt with in a safe way.

Comment: node-mysql has escaped / parameterized queries. You have to check with the documentation, and if this isn't noted, with the source code of sequelize if raw queries work the same ways as with node-mysql. The escape function is bound to the connection so you should be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like not. We are actually moving away from Sequelize into Node-mysql, it just doesn't do enough. In particular, if you want multiple connections, you have to replicate your entire definitions file. We are sharding our database, and have a set up a fairly simple method using node-mysql. It's nice to be able to code SQL again.